# Add Sass (.scss) to ejected create-react-app config

Tags: reactjs, sass, webpack, create-react-app

I want to add `.scss` support in my app, which was created using create-react-app.

I did eject `npm run eject` and installed necessary dependencies: `npm install sass-loader node-sass --save-dev`

Inside `config/webpack.config.dev.js` I added to the loaders this snippet:

```
{
   test: /\.scss$/,
   include: paths.appSrc,
   loaders: ["style", "css", "scss"]
},
```

So the beginning of the loaders array now look like so:

```
loaders: [
      // Process JS with Babel.
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        include: paths.appSrc,
        loader: 'babel',
        query: require('./babel.dev')
      },
      // "postcss" loader applies autoprefixer to our CSS.
      // "css" loader resolves paths in CSS and adds assets as dependencies.
      // "style" loader turns CSS into JS modules that inject <style> tags.
      // In production, we use a plugin to extract that CSS to a file, but
      // in development "style" loader enables hot editing of CSS.
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: 'style!css!postcss'
      },
      // LOAD & COMPILE SCSS
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        include: paths.appSrc,
        loaders: ["style", "css", "scss"]
      },
```

Now in my jsx when I try to import scss file:

```
import './assets/app.scss';
```

I get an error:

> Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "./assets/app.scss"

So my config must be wrong as I'm not able to load `.scss` files. How to adjust config to load `.scss` files in ejected `create-react-app`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OK, I found the solution - changed from this:

```
{
    test: /\.scss$/,
    include: paths.appSrc,
    loaders: ["style", "css", "scss"]
},
```

to this:

```
{
    test: /\.scss$/,
    loaders: ['style', 'css', 'sass']
},
```

And now my `.scss` files are loading!!

Comment: or `{
            test: /\.scss$/,
            include: path.appSrc,
            loaders: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
          },` 
worked for me

Answer (score 9):

Check the first loader, first it get all the files and it excludes the other loaders files

```
loaders: [
        {
            exclude: [
                /\.html$/,
                /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                /\.css$/,
                /\.json$/,
                /\.svg$/
            ],
            loader: 'url',
            query: {
                limit: 10000,
                name: 'static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]'
            }
        },
```

so adding

```
/\.sass$/,
/\.scss$/,
```

to exclude, seems that fixed the same problem I had :D

Answer (score 9):

When trying to integrate sass into empty react project I used this [article](https://medium.com/@Connorelsea/using-sass-with-create-react-app-7125d6913760). The solution presented there did not work and received the similar error as in the subject. 
In my case replacing `style-loader` with `require.resolve('style-loader')` helped:

```
 {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        include: paths.appSrc,
        loaders: [require.resolve('style-loader'), require.resolve('css-loader'), require.resolve('sass-loader')]
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably have to use

```
include: paths.appSrc,
```

option to enable webpack hot-reload. So you config snippet could looks like

```
{
    test: /\.scss$/,
    include: paths.appSrc,
    loaders: ['style', 'css', 'sass']
},
```

Answer (score 1):

as per Latest Configuration [CRA]

::webpack.config.dev.js::

```
{
    test: /\.css$/,
    use: [
      require.resolve('style-loader'),
      {
        loader: require.resolve('css-loader'),
        options: {
          importLoaders: 1,
        },
      },
      {
        loader: require.resolve('postcss-loader'),
        options: {
          // Necessary for external CSS imports to work
          // https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/2677
          ident: 'postcss',
          plugins: () => [
            require('postcss-flexbugs-fixes'),
            autoprefixer({
              browsers: [
                '>1%',
                'last 4 versions',
                'Firefox ESR',
                'not ie < 9', // React doesn't support IE8 anyway
              ],
              flexbox: 'no-2009',
            }),
          ],
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    test: /\.scss$/,
    loaders: [
        require.resolve("style-loader"), // creates style nodes from JS strings
        require.resolve("css-loader"), // transl ates CSS into CommonJS
        require.resolve("sass-loader") // compiles Sass to CSS
      ]
  },
```

Comment: Not working for me. Message: `Module build failed: TypeError: this.getResolve is not a function`

Answer (score 0):

Check this loader settings for the latest versions.

```
{
     test: /\.scss$/,
     use: [
         "style-loader", // creates style nodes from JS strings
         "css-loader", // translates CSS into CommonJS
         "sass-loader" // compiles Sass to CSS
    ]
}
```