# sass not working in create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, webpack, sass, create-react-app, node-sass-chokidar

Sass does not compiling in create-react-app. The current package.json structure is

```
{
  "name": "create-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "node-sass-chokidar": "^1.2.2",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.2",
    "react": "^16.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.3.1",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-scripts": "^1.1.4",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build-css": "node-sass-chokidar src/ -o src/",
    "watch-css": "npm run build-css && node-sass-chokidar src/ -o src/ --watch --recursive",
    "start-js": "react-scripts start",
    "start": "npm-run-all -p watch-css start-js",
    "build-js": "react-scripts build",
    "build": "npm-run-all build-css build-js",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

Repo: https://github.com/athimannil/create-app

[image]

Comment: Create-react-app uses PostCSS by default, as it is a more modern / modular approach. If you need to use Sass, you will need to update the CSS loader inside webpack.config for the environment you want to use. Please post your webpack config with the question.

Comment: You can probably find the answer with steps to your issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40486756/add-sass-to-ejected-create-react-app-config/40487714#40487714

Comment: @Vlatko Vlahek I simply followed create-react-app documentation https://github.com/athimannil/create-app#adding-a-css-preprocessor-sass-less-etc

Comment: Have you done `npm run watch-css`?

Comment: @Muhammed if you are using *npm start*, it should work. Can you post the log from the terminal when you run the command? Maybe its something silly, like missing ; inside the scss file or something similar.

Comment: @VlatkoVlahek Exactly, as you can see in the repo it is simply following documentation  https://github.com/athimannil/create-app

Comment: Ok. Then, what about terminal / command prompt log. Are there any errors there after running npm start?

Comment: @VlatkoVlahek Terminal doesn't say anything. At the same time localhost not giving any css style which we did in scss file and also terminal shows it compile when make chances in .scss

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is working fine, `npm start` watch your `.scss` files and output `.css` files as expected.

Make sure to require the `.css` files in your components.

> Since `src/App.js` still imports `src/App.css`, the styles become a part of your application. You can now edit `src/App.scss`, and `src/App.css` will be regenerated.

Also since `.css` files are now generated, you should remove them from your SCM.

> At this point you might want to remove all CSS files from the source control, and add `src/**/*.css` to your `.gitignore` file.

[doc](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#adding-a-css-preprocessor-sass-less-etc)

Answer (score 2):

The [2. version of create-react-app](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/10/01/create-react-app-v2.html) supports Sass now. Install node-sass (e.g. npm install node-sass) to enable it. Checkout this [application's Navigation component](https://github.com/the-road-to-learn-react/create-react-app-with-sass).